# Laggy video and longer duration than the original file

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a file with this output in ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2021-01-01-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[mpeg2video @ 000002e8de943080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 5 times
[s302m @ 000002e8de960780] S302 non PCM mode with data type 28 not supported
[mpeg2video @ 000002e8de943080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[s302m @ 000002e8de960780] S302 non PCM mode with data type 28 not supported
[mpeg2video @ 000002e8de943080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[s302m @ 000002e8de960780] S302 non PCM mode with data type 28 not supported
[mpeg2video @ 000002e8de943080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[s302m @ 000002e8de960780] S302 non PCM mode with data type 28 not supported
[mpeg2video @ 000002e8de943080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[s302m @ 000002e8de960780] S302 non PCM mode with data type 28 not supported
[mpeg2video @ 000002e8de943080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[s302m @ 000002e8de960780] S302 non PCM mode with data type 28 not supported
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 000002e8de943080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[s302m @ 000002e8de960780] S302 non PCM mode with data type 28 not supported
[mpeg2video @ 000002e8de943080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[s302m @ 000002e8de960780] S302 non PCM mode with data type 28 not supported
[mpeg2video @ 000002e8de943080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[s302m @ 000002e8de960780] S302 non PCM mode with data type 28 not supported
[mpeg2video @ 000002e8de943080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[s302m @ 000002e8de960780] S302 non PCM mode with data type 28 not supported
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 000002e8de943080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[s302m @ 000002e8de960780] S302 non PCM mode with data type 28 not supported
[mpeg2video @ 000002e8de943080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[s302m @ 000002e8de960780] S302 non PCM mode with data type 28 not supported
[mpeg2video @ 000002e8de943080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[s302m @ 000002e8de960780] S302 non PCM mode with data type 28 not supported
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 000002e8de943080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[s302m @ 000002e8de960780] S302 non PCM mode with data type 28 not supported
    Last message repeated 4 times
[mpegts @ 000002e8de93cbc0] decoding for stream 3 failed
[mpegts @ 000002e8de93cbc0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 3 (Audio: s302m (BSSD / 0x44535342), stereo, s32 (20 bit), 2304 kb/s): unspecified sample rate
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'G:\test\test.ts':
  Duration: 03:27:29.61, start: 3.000000, bitrate: 39124 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x200]: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv422p(tv, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 450 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 36898800/0/0 buffer size: 13271040 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1[0x1010]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1020]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x1030]: Audio: s302m (BSSD / 0x44535342), stereo, s32 (20 bit), 2304 kb/s
```

But whatever setting i try the video ends up very laggy and the duration ends up much longer than the original file, even when I play it through VLC. It is a little hard to explain so I will provide a sample file here with the result after the conversion:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ADPF2POSnBCiJkgMES2vOn2wznyBst6W/view?usp=sharing

Is it something wrong with the file or with ffmpeg itself and how do I solve it?

Firstly I tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -i "G:\test\test.ts" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec libx265 -crf 23 -filter:v yadif=1 -acodec ac3 -ab 384k "C:\Users\User name\Videos\test.mkv"
```

And then I tried this with the same result:

```
ffmpeg -i "G:\test\test.ts" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy "C:\Users\User name\Videos\test.mkv"
```

The sample file is converted with the first command.

Comment: Your command is missing.

Comment: @llogan Sorry, it is fixed now.